# how to test models and methods which define in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

please tell me what is the main thing to test the models with rspec, I am testing only validations part like email and password etc and it is necessary to test the methods which is defined in model.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are only testing validations, you should use this:

```
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers
```

If you want to test methods (any method, not just validation methods), you'll have to evaluate each response possibility according to what you defined as its behaviour.

```
describe "semaphore" do
  describe "#turn_green" do
    it "should turn green" do
      subject.turn_green.should == "green"
    end
    it "should not turn red" do
      subject.turn_green.should_not == "red"
    end
  end
end
```